# Arduino compiler and STL: Using std::vector and std::map

Tags: c++, arduino, stl, arduino-esp8266

While many posts say the STL libs are not generally available for arduino/embedded systems they seem to be installed on my Arduino compiler!  And many work.

**Problem:**  (complete sketch shown)

```
std::vector<int> foo;         // this works fine
std::map<int,int> bar;    // adding this gives an error

void setup() {}
void loop() {}


sketch_jun05a:4:1: error: 'map' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::map<int,int> bar;
 ^
```

**So I don't know why std::vector would work but std::map would not work.**

compiler platform:  Ardunio.app 1.8.12 on Mac OSX Catalina 
Targeting:  ESP8266

*Detailed error message is pasted below.*

**Analysis:**
I went searching for map.h inside my arduino application  and I found what looks to be an extensive set STL library classes including stl_map.h

these are located on my system at this path:

```
~/Library/Arduino15/packages//esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/xtensa-lx106-elf/include/c++/4.8.2

and most of the interesting looking headers are in a subdir called "bits".
```

The other strange thing is that std::vector works without including any header files.  That's unexpected to me.

I have not configured my search paths or set any environment variables so whatever the Arduino App does as installed is what path it is searching on.

**I also can't find any documentation on this.**
Everything I do find says there isn't an STL for Arduino/ESP8266!  I did find some gitbub project libraries named ArduinoSTL and avr_stl which previously I did install as local user libraries (not in the system libs)  but I am not importing these in the sketch above.

Here is the full error message:

```
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/cems/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:d1:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=legacy,ssl=all,eesz=4M2M,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=3000000 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10812 -build-path /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_cache_761223 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-2.5.0-4-b40a506.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-2.5.0-4-b40a506.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3-3.7.2-post1.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mklittlefs/2.5.0-4-fe5bb56 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs-2.5.0-4-fe5bb56.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mklittlefs/2.5.0-4-fe5bb56 -verbose /Users/cems/Documents/Arduino/sketch_jun05a/sketch_jun05a.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/cems/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=esp8266:esp8266:d1:xtal=80,vt=flash,exception=legacy,ssl=all,eesz=4M2M,ip=lm2f,dbg=Disabled,lvl=None____,wipe=none,baud=3000000 -vid-pid=1A86_7523 -ide-version=10812 -build-path /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_cache_761223 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc-2.5.0-4-b40a506.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.mkspiffs-2.5.0-4-b40a506.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mkspiffs/2.5.0-4-b40a506 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.python3-3.7.2-post1.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mklittlefs/2.5.0-4-fe5bb56 -prefs=runtime.tools.mklittlefs-2.5.0-4-fe5bb56.path=/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/mklittlefs/2.5.0-4-fe5bb56 -verbose /Users/cems/Documents/Arduino/sketch_jun05a/sketch_jun05a.ino
Using board 'd1' from platform in folder: /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1
Using core 'esp8266' from platform in folder: /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1
Detecting libraries used...
/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/include -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/core -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_WEMOS_D1R1 -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_WEMOS_D1R1\"" -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/cores/esp8266 -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/variants/d1 /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/sketch/sketch_jun05a.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
Generating function prototypes...
/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/include -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/core -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -w -x c++ -E -CC -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_WEMOS_D1R1 -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_WEMOS_D1R1\"" -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/cores/esp8266 -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/variants/d1 /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/sketch/sketch_jun05a.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
Compiling sketch...
/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/python3/3.7.2-post1/python3 /Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/signing.py --mode header --publickey /Users/cems/Documents/Arduino/sketch_jun05a/public.key --out /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/core/Updater_Signing.h
/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++ -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/include -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/lwip2/include -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include -I/var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/core -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=gnu++11 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -DNONOSDK22x_190703=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0 -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_WEMOS_D1R1 -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 "-DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_WEMOS_D1R1\"" -DFLASHMODE_DIO -DESP8266 -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/cores/esp8266 -I/Users/cems/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.1/variants/d1 /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/sketch/sketch_jun05a.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/py/rycjfnrd0t13_pm4d11yyd2m0000gn/T/arduino_build_263707/sketch/sketch_jun05a.ino.cpp.o
sketch_jun05a:4:1: error: 'stl_map' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::stl_map<int,int> bar;
 ^
exit status 1
'stl_map' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

Comment: Show us a full file that tries to use std::map, with the #includes and all.  Also, if you'd describe the problem you're going to solve using std::map that would help a lot.  I bet there's a better solution.

Comment: @JohnZwinck  the question here is if the STL is available in ESP8266 (Arduino compiler) or not?  if it is where is the documentation on this?  As for solving any specific usecase there are lots of ways to roll your own map() class but if one has an STL available a lot of code ports easily.  I'm just using the map() case to show that apparently some of the STL isn't there and some is.  That's odd since the ESP8266 libraries seem to include both vector and map.  So why not map() compiling but vector() does?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone :

You can find a (very old) STL port for Arduino IDE here :
https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus

**NOTE AFTER TESTING:**  Well, well,well... that particular library is buggy (with nasty off-by-one errors! especially in the classes I didn't wanted to reinvent).

Comment: Does it still work?  will it break other things that use stdlib and expect some other stdlib?

Comment: @Alexander As far as `std::bitset<>`  is concerned, this not working out of the box..

Answer (score 0):

Mysteriously, vector was included elsewhere by the esp8266 core, while map was not. Fortunately, explicitly including map kept my compiler happy. Arduino IDE 1.8.13, esp8266 core 3.02, windows 7 32-bit.

Also true for other STL templates, like std::string, #include <string>

```
std::vector<int> foo;       // vector 'mysteriously' included elsewhere by esp8266 core
// As suggested by compiler along with 'map' error if map not user included:
//  "note: 'std::map' is defined in header '<map>'; did you forget to '#include <map>'?"
#include <map>              // user must include to use std::map (see above comment)
std::map<int, int> bar;
```